# C++ "Windows.h" equivalent on Android

Tags: android, c++

I tried short programs with a compiler for Android on my mobile called CforDroid. It worked fine except when the code contains a header called "Windows.h". My aim is to manipulate the screen buffer for simple games without graphics even on Android.

```
    // Create Screen Buffer
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight; i++) screen[i] = L' ';
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
```

Are there any equivalent commands with Android? Or where can I find documentation for Android?

Comment: You either need to look at the documentation for C4Droid/CForDroid/whichever app you're actually using, or look up the Android SDK.

Comment: Instead of asking "What's the equivalent of windows.h on Android?" try asking about the thing you are trying to do, which is to display characters in different places on the screen instead of just the end. Note that Android doesn't *have* a terminal. It's something that CForDroid added in. So you should probably look at the documentation about CForDroid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way on Android to match that. There are probably 3 ways to write C/C++ code for Android:

1. Totally "command" app: create a traditional app similar to [this one](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/android-mk/test-libstdc%2B%2B/jni), and run it with `adb push $your-app /sdcard/local/tmp`, `adb shell`,`/data/local/tmp/$app-name`. It is bare linux, not an Android app actually. Your commercial app will be in this way as it can not access store at all (no billing).
2. Create Java/Kotlin app, which is the "new and normal world" for Android, then use JNI to bridge you to your C/C++ code. Here you start with Activity and lots of materials available already.
3. Something in between, is this thing called [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity), which is now succeeded by [GameActivity](https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity). With this, you start with the given android_main() function, and add your own C/C++ code. In this way, you might be quickly get your C/C++ code tested.  Bear in mind that they  are still Java activities, just that extra code wraps the Activity, converts and passes the app commands to your C/C++ side (by android_native_app_glue component): the "Java new world" is still there in your app, just got hidden behind the native_app_glue code. This way, you deal less with Java/Kotlin for your core app logic; however, when getting down to play store related things, it is only Java/Kotlin.

C4Droid probably uses certain template internally to hide the Java side things so you get to create C/C++ code in a "box", which is a portion of Android app execution environment. In the end you most likely still need to get familiar with Java/Kotlin things on Android when creating formal Android apps.